# Facebook Audience network : ads not showing on the android web browser

Tags: facebook, native-ads

I have implemented facebook native ads in my website - advert approved by the facebook and it's live now. and it's shown on the windows and iphone's web browser. but is not showing on the android web browser

Please share any idea on this